# Exporting NDVI Data with Google Earth Engine not working as expected

Tags: javascript, google-fusion-tables, google-earth-engine

I am an Editor for a German newspaper with just rudimentary scripting skills. 
[This code makes it possible to analyze NDVI data for 50 cities in Germany to calculate the green amount for each citiy.](https://gist.github.com/funkeinteraktiv/22e034f45dfff8efc6594e5327c74ee3)

With

```
var germany = ee.FeatureCollection('ft:1KDrYXBDlAx1fhcfmWRx7u_qqN2O_gwBNInjnGmnZ');
var cities = ee.FeatureCollection('ft:1w4PgU3okfzwKFEIpH32oPMlOtei6hUWa9tkXv5Rt');
```

the script loads a google fusion table with a germany shape and a table with geometries for the cities. Everything works fine so far.
But if I change fusion tables to

```
var germany = ee.FeatureCollection('ft:1M7PhnbkAGZuKp4hnanZQlaoNOSDnnOSQdeIPUZwS'); 
var cities = ee.FeatureCollection('ft:1K9Km7OyeCyJZMWhZOob_OiHJZbcO2uTWoNS9p1-h');
```

to use different geometries, it is not working anymore. Neither it is showing the geometries in GEE nor the exported NDVI Green Amount data is correct (it shows just 0 für every polygon).

Any clues what I could do to fix this?

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: Do the new tables have the required columns and column types? At least one of them is private so you'll have to [do your homework](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Problem solved. There must have been an error in the dataset. Now I tried a different one and it works as expected.